# How do I modify the gym's environment CarRacing-v0?

Tags: openai-gym

I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a tutorial or any information about how to modify the environment CarRacing-v0 from openai gym, more exactly how to create different roads, I haven't found anything about it.

What I want to do is to create a track more difficult, with T-junction, narrow streets in some points maybe add some obstacles, etc. I have been looking at `_create_track`in `car_racing.py` but modifying it looks rather tedious and I don't want to start working on it if there is another easier solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that there was not answer I have modified the environment by reading and understanding the code, it is not that hard, I will leave the repo just in case it is useful for someone else

https://github.com/NotAnyMike/gym

Some screenshots of the modifications:

Complex Map:

[image: complex maps]

Complex intersections:

[image]

And some obstacles:

[image]

To see more and the updated version see the repo on github.

Comment: hey @Mike how to change the map in your repo

Comment: The maps are randomly generated or loaded. Check https://github.com/NotAnyMike/gym/blob/794bcdf7f1e2a13c47451b6132b6e7ac626cf8d8/gym/envs/box2d/car_racing.py#L275